# Точка входа в .NET dll

Tags: .net

Существует ли стандартный механизм, с помощью которого можно было бы автоматически выполнять определённый код при загрузке сборки в домен? Понятно, что реализовать такое несложно (пометить сборки своим атрибутом, указывающим тип, в статический конструктор которого следует поместить код инициализации, подписаться на `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoaded` и дёргать в обработчике указанный тип, если сборка помечена), но всё же хотелось бы использовать стандартный механизм, если есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично мне кажется, что event `AssemblyLoaded` как раз и является *"стандартным механизмом"* для таких целей.

А как его применять - *т.е все то, что написано у вас в вопросе, включая использование кастомных атрибутов и пометку сборок* - это просто некоторый `syntactic sugar`, который так или иначе диспатчит `AssemblyLoaded`.

---

Другое дело, что в общем случае задача выполнения нужного кода в момент загрузки некоторой сборки нетривиальна и корректно решается только с помощью `module initializers.`

*Рекомендую к прочтению [.Net: Running code when assembly is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505237/net-running-code-when-assembly-is-loaded), если есть еще вопросы, то готов ответить.*